# How to configure GOPATH?

Tags: go, goland

I installed Goland as a Go IDE and it wants me to configure GOPATH. I'm new in this language so I don't know what to do. Here is the error message:

> GOPATH was detected
>               We've detected some libraries from your GOPATH.
>               You may want to add extra libraries in GOPATH configuration.

Edit: Not a duplicate question, `export GOROOT=""`solved my problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7):

[You actually do not need to set the `GOPATH` environment variable; in Go 1.8 it's `~/go` by default.](https://beta.golang.org/doc/go1.8#gopath)

I suggest that you just update to latest stable Go (1.8) and use that convention; otherwise you'll need to set the `GOPATH` variable in your environment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `GOPATH` environment variable. How you do this varies depending on your operating system.

Here are examples of [how to set the PATH environment variable](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml), just modify the instructions to set `GOPATH` instead.

Also see [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces) for more details on setting up your workspace and setting `GOPATH`.

Answer (score 1):

```
export GOROOT=""
```

solved the issue for some reason.